# How to get bit width in PyGears?

Tags: python, pygears

How do I calculate in PyGears how many bits do I need to represent some numbers, for example:
4,6,-100 etc.

Is it possible to use log2 function?

Answer (score 1):

For most use cases it is probably best to convert them to PyGears types first, since this will allow you to perform some other actions useful for hardware design.

For the integers, you can use `Integer` generic type to automatically infer the corresponding integer hardware type of the number:

```
>>> from pygears.typing import Integer
>>> Integer(4)
Uint[3](4)
>>> Integer(6)
Uint[3](6)
>>> Integer(-100)
Int[8](-100)
```

Every PyGears type supports the `width` attribute, so if you are interested only in the bit width of the number representation, you can do the following:

```
>>> Integer(4).width
3
>>> Integer(6).width
3
>>> Integer(-100).width
8
```

This also takes care of some special cases like:

```
>>> Integer(0)
Uint[1](0)
```

For an example one additional useful functionality all PyGears types support is calculating the binary representation itself via `code()` method:

```
>>> hex(Integer(-100).code())
'0x9c'
```

For the sake of completeness, if you are really only interested in the bit width on the number, you can use the function `bitw()` from `pygears.typing`:

```
>>> bitw(4)
3
>>> bitw(6)
3
>>> bitw(-100)
8
```